# Executing functions in bulk mode in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, bulkinsert

I have a very special use case to implement. In order to improve performance of a process that writes information into a MongoDB Collection, I am trying to use [bulk writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods). The "special" side of the requirements is that some operations are something like the following:

```
// Firt of all, try the update
var result = db.test.update(
  { /* Omissis*/ },
  {$inc :{ /* Omissis */ }},
  {upsert: false}
);
// If the update do not succeed, then try to insert the document
if (result.nModified === 0) {
  try {
    db.test.insert(/* Put here the whole document */);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  // Here we are sure that the document exists.
  // Retry to execute the update statement
  db.test.update(/* Same update as above */);
}
```

These statements should be performed in the given order and with the given logic.

If I defined a function in MongoDB which body is represented by the above code, is it possible to call it in bulk mode? If possible, the given solution should be something that is reproducible with the Java driver.

Thanks to all.